# GridBagLayout in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, autolayout

Is there any feature equivalent to "GridBagLayout as in swing" in cocoa?
Spent some time in searching with no luck.

Any help or suggestions to create something like GridBagLayout in cocoa is appreciated:)
Thanks:)

Comment: It'd be helpful to people not familiar with Swing if you'd post an explanation or screenshot of GridBagLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't. Closest thing to `GridBagLayout` in Java is probably the `NSCollectionView` displaying an array of content as a grid of views:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCollectionView_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCollectionView_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSCollectionView

Comment: Thanks jay, I s there anyone who tried something like this? if so Kindly revert..Thanks:)

Comment: Well, there are code samples for the `NSCollectionView` like [this one](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/IconCollection/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: I have already worked with NSCollectionView..(Wrote my own custom control using NSCollectionView and view based table view)..Thank you very much for your interest and reply:)

Comment: I have accepted your answer, which says there isn't :) but i am sure many have tried this, if so kindly share your ideas:) thanks in advance.